# How to sum two neighbours in a list in scala

Tags: scala, list, recursion, sum, pattern-matching

If you have one Integer list in Scala, and you want to iterate through it and sum every two neighbours with the same value and return this as a list, how would one do that ?

So for example:

```
List(4, 4, 2, 6) => List(8, 2, 6)
```

I'm completely new to Scala, but I can imagine that pattern match or map could be useful.

```
def sumSameNeighbours: List[Int] => List[Int] = {
  ls match {
    case l1::l2:ls => l1 == l2
  }
}
```

This is what I can think of.

EDIT: How would I have to change the code in order to iterate from right to left instead from left to right?

So that f.e. it would be:

```
List(2, 2, 2, 6, 4) => List(2, 4, 6, 4)
```

instead of

```
List(2, 2, 2, 6, 4) => List(4, 2, 6, 4)
```

Comment: What would be the expected result for `List(4, 4, 4, 2, 6)`?

Comment: That would be List(8, 4, 2, 6)

Comment: What about `List(2, 4, 4, 2, 6)`? Is it unchanged, or does it produce `List(2, 8, 2, 6)`? A few more examples would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that would be `List(2, 8, 2, 6)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty close to your suggestion and seems basically to work:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def sumSameNeighbors( ls : List[Int] ) : List[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def walk( unsummed : List[Int], reverseAccum : List[Int] ) : List[Int] = {
    unsummed match {
      case a :: b :: rest if a == b => walk( rest, a + b :: reverseAccum )
      case a :: rest                => walk( rest, a :: reverseAccum )
      case Nil                      => reverseAccum.reverse
    }
  }
  walk( ls, Nil )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems to work good. One further question: How would I have to change the code in order to iterate from right to left instead from left to right? So that f.e. it would be List(2, 2, 2, 6, 4) => List(2, 4, 6, 4)

Comment: the easy way would just be `def sumSameNeighborsFromRight( ls : List[Int] ) = sumSameNeighbors( ls.reverse ).reverse`.

Answer (score 3):

***Note:*** Based on final OP's specifications clarification, this answer doesn't exactly fit the question requirements.

Here is a solution using [`List.grouped(2)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]):

```
list.grouped(2).toList
  .flatMap {
    case List(a, b) if a == b => List(a + b)
    case l => l
  }
```

The idea is to group consecutive elements by pair. If the pair has the same elements, we return their sum to be flatMaped and otherwise both elements untouched.

```
List(4, 4, 2, 6) => List(8, 2, 6)
List(2, 4, 4, 2, 6) => List(2, 4, 4, 2, 6)
List(2) => List(2)
List(9, 4, 4, 4, 2, 6) => List(9, 4, 8, 2, 6)
```

Comment: This would break if the input just started with a single unique number. The question doesn't really mention that though but it might be a good assumption.

Comment: Yeah, break was the wrong word as only the op would know what `List(9, 4, 4, 4, 2, 6)` should return. Steve's result would be different that's all.

Comment: @XavierGuihot This solution is wrong, it does not produce the correct answers. See the comments on the question for the correct transformation for `List(2, 4, 4, 2, 6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `foldRight`, which I find a good default for this sort of traversing a collection while creating a new one:

```
list.foldRight(List.empty[Int]) {
  case (x, y :: tail) if x == y => (x + y) :: tail
  case (x, list) => x :: list
}
```

Output of `List(2, 2, 2, 6, 4)` is `List(2, 4, 6, 4)` as requested.

The main thing I wasn't clear on from your examples is what the output should be if summing creates new neighbours: should `List(8, 4, 2, 2)` turn into `List(8, 4, 4)` or `List(16)`? This produces the second.